# How to fix progress resetting when i switch my tabs

Tags: javascript, html

Im making a game with tabs and as it stands progress between tabs resets when I change tabs  http://prntscr.com/ns2jvg   http://prntscr.com/ns2k31  http://prntscr.com/ns2k74     I know eventually i'll make a last tab called options that you can use to reset. but i would like for development to be able to debug and be able to switch tabs with no reset

Im not sure how this is done im new to html

This is my Home Tab in html:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title> Basic Clicker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="nav_bar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="GameMainWindow.html" id="onlink">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="SkillTree.html">SkillTree</a></li>
            <li><a href="Equipment.html">Equipment</a></li>
            <li><a href="Pets.html">Pets</a></li>
            <li><a href="Skills.html">Skills</a></li>
            <li><a href="Quests.html">Quests</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main_container">
        <p>
            <html>

            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="interface.css" />
            </head>
            <title> Basic Clicker</title>

            <body>
```

This is the next tab in html:

```
<html>

<head>
        <title> Basic Clicker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="nav_bar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="GameMainWindow.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="SkillTree.html" id="onlink">SkillTree</a></li>
            <li><a href="Equipment.html">Equipment</a></li>
            <li><a href="Pets.html">Pets</a></li>
            <li><a href="Skills.html">Skills</a></li>
            <li><a href="Quests.html">Quests</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main_container">
        <p>
            <html>

            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="interface.css" />
            </head>
            <title> Basic Clicker</title>

            <body>
```

I expect the tabs to switch and for the player to not lose any data/ it not to reset. right now things reset when you click a different tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of **[`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)**.

On page one you can add an item into `localStorage` with:

```
localStorage.setItem('pet', 'Cat'); // name, value
```

And on page two you can retrieve the value with:

```
var pet = localStorage.getItem('pet');
```

You can also overwrite the value later on, or remove it with:

```
localStorage.removeItem('pet'); // remove an individual item
localStorage.clear(); // remove all items
```

Note that `localStorage` **persists** across browser sessions. If you want to restrict the storage to an individual session, you should instead make use of **[`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)**.

Comment: thanks ive never used this before can u give me a example on where to put that in my code to make it functioning? for example my skill points carrying over to the skill tree tab ( it adds one to a counter when u rebirth) or the other way around hp up going to home tab